# Auto increment in TableView using JavaFX is not sorting

Tags: javafx

I found a "Simple alternate solution" in [auto numbered table rows (javafx)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384879/auto-numbered-table-rows-javafx) for auto-incrementing values

1. This works well. However, if I sort the column in the table, this is not getting sorted. Any fix for this?
2. Also, according the solution if I delete a row in the middle and write the table contents to a file, the row number is adjusted in the table view but not in the file. The row will be deleted in the file but the auto-incremented value does not get adjusted. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a persistent numbering which is attached to the data objects so that the numbers get sorted with the data objects, then you should create a data item which includes the numbering.

For example:

```
public class IdentifiedPerson {
  private IntegerProperty id;
  private ObjectProperty<Person> person;

  public IdentifiedPerson(int id, Person person) {
    this.id = new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
    this.person = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(person);
  }

  public IntegerProperty idProperty() {
    return id;
  }

  public ObjectProperty<Person> personProperty() {
    return person;
  }
}
```

Then your TableView is defined as:

```
private TableView<IdentifiedPerson> table = new TableView<IdentifiedPerson>();
```

And you provide cell value factories for each of your table columns to supply the relevant data (either the person id or some person attribute).

So the id/row number essentially becomes part of your object model.  If you can modify the Person object directly, then you can stick the id in there rather than having the wrapper class for the person id + person object.

Anyway, I think the above info will help you solve your issues.  If not, or if you can't come up with a working example yourself, add some further comments or edit the question and maybe somebody can put an example together for you.