# TableView Auto Updation Column

Tags: javafx

I am using `TableView`, in this there a button to delete the row, `S.no` column have to update automatically

```
public void Delete()
{

    int myIndex = 
               MyTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
    System.out.println(myIndex);

    ObservableList<Parent> selectedRow, allParents;
    allParents = MyTable.getItems();

    selectedRow = MyTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItems();

    for(Parent parent : selectedRow)    
    {
        allParents.remove(parent);
    }


    for (int i=myIndex; ts.getCellData(i)!=null;i++)
    {


        System.out.println(i+1);
// I need here to update my column with the following values

        MyTable.getItems().forEach(item -> item.setId(k));
// I tried the above code but it display the same values in the S.no column
    }

}



// This is my TableView Model
public class Parent {

    private SimpleStringProperty ts, eo;
    private SimpleIntegerProperty id;

    Parent(Integer id, String ts, String eo){
        this.id= new SimpleIntegerProperty(id);
        this.ts= new SimpleStringProperty(ts);
        this.eo= new SimpleStringProperty(eo);
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id.get();
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id.set(id);
    }

    public String getTs() {
        return ts.get();
    }

    public void setTs(String ts) {
        this.ts.set(ts);
    }

    public String getEo() {
        return eo.get();
    }

    public void setEo(String eo) {
        this.eo.set(eo);
    }

}
```

expecting the results in `S.no` is

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

but results are getting like

```
1
2
3
5
6
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. And unrelated to your problem: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Comment: No Idea how you set the column you ask about up. No idea what `k` is supposed to refer to either. You need to add more info to the question to be answerable.

Comment: I would suggest taking the `id` out of your `TableView`. Use the `id` under the hood. To show row number, I would suggest something from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16384879/auto-numbered-table-rows-javafx.